# mariadb multiplatform project

Tags: c++, c, linux, mariadb

I'm trying to create a cross-platform application that is using client applications written in C for MariaDB. But MariaDB offers a different library for each operating system and architecture for each of these. I need to know if there is a way to set up a C++ project for when you compile on Windows then take Windows libraries and when I compile on Linux then take the Linux ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux you'll want to use the distribution's repository's mariadb, on Windows, you'll need to compile it yourself or ship the official release.

It's best to use something lik CMake which allows you to either detect the presence of a library or let the builder point it to where it can be found at build time, and don't hardcode any paths or crazy platform-dependent search paths into your build system's project file.

Comment: thanks for the reply rubenvb, I'll take that in mind. The problem it is a requierement of my library to be cross-platform and I need to use MariaDb client to connect with the database.

Comment: @yosoy: that should be no problem, but you'll need to compile the client library for each platform you want to compile your program for. No way around that in C/C++ land.